# Compare 2 corresponding elements in list in python and print them separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists:

```
x=[[3, 'id1', 50],[1, 'id2', 34],[2, 'id3', 39],[5, 'id2', 26],[4,'id3', 23]]  
y=[5,6,4,4,3]
```

Based on a condition, lets say if i filter `x` with `'id2'`, i get the list as `[[1, 'id2', 34],[5, 'id2', 26]]`.
Now i want to print the corresponding values in list `y` which in this case will be `[6,4]`
I am able to filter the elements from the first list based on the condition but not able to find a way to get the corresponding data from second list.
How can this be accomplished in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` to iterate through lists simultaneously:

```
x = [[3, 'id1', 50],[1, 'id2', 34],[2, 'id3', 39],[5, 'id2', 26],[4,'id3', 23]]
y = [5,6,4,4,3]

lst = [b for a, b in zip(x, y) if a[1] == 'id2']
# [6, 4]
```

If you need contents of both `x` and `y` lists:

```
lst1, lst2 = zip(*[(a, b) for a, b in zip(x, y) if a[1] == 'id2'])

print(lst1)  # ([1, 'id2', 34], [5, 'id2', 26])
print(lst2)  # (6, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for simple solution. I was able to get the right response. I will accept the answer once it let me do that.